# How to change expansion panel icon position to the left?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, accordion

In my app, the expansion arrow has to be in the left side of the panel.
But, by default it's displaying in the right side.

This :

```
<ExpansionPanelSummary
    className={classes.panelSummary}
    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
    IconButtonProps={{edge: 'start'}}
    aria-controls='panel1a-content'
    id='panel1a-header'
>
```

Doesn't made it.

Comment: No there is no way by using the normal api. The order is set within their code.

Answer (score 15):

Granted, you can't (easily) change the order in which the components appear in the HTML. However, there is a way using only CSS. `ExpansionPanelSummary` uses `display: flex`; you can therefore set the `order` property on the icon to make it appear to the left of the content.

This can be achieved with either `useStyles` or `withStyles` (Or possibly using plain CSS, but I haven't tried it); here's how you'd go about using the latter:

```js
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";

const IconLeftExpansionPanelSummary = withStyles({
    expandIcon: {
        order: -1
    }
})(ExpansionPanelSummary);
```

You can then write the rest of your code using `IconLeftExpansionPanelSummary` instead of `ExpansionPanelSummary` when you want the icon to appear to the left. Don't forget to set `IconButtonProps={{edge: 'start'}}` on the component for proper spacing.

Comment: As of material-ui/core 4.11.0, ExpansionPanel is called Accordion, but this helpful answer still works.

Answer (score 14):

```xml
<AccordionSummary
  className={classes.accordionSummary}
  classes={{
    expandIcon: classes.expandIcon,
    expanded: classes.expanded
  }}
  IconButtonProps={{
    disableRipple: true
  }}
></AccordionSummary>
```

You can add class and use flex-direction

```js
accordionSummary: {
  flexDirection: 'row-reverse'
}
```

Comment: In short, written differently:
`<AccordionSummary sx={{flexDirection: "row-reverse"}}></AccordionSummary>`

Answer (score 5):

It's simple

1. add class on `<ExpansionPanelSummary>` like this

`<ExpansionPanelSummary className={classes.panelSummary}>`

2. add css against this class in jss like this

`panelSummary:{flexDirection: "row-reverse"},`

---

**In case using css**

1. add class on `<ExpansionPanelSummary>` like this

`<ExpansionPanelSummary className="panelSummary">`

2. add css against this class in jss like this

`.panelSummary{flex-direction: row-reverse;}`

Answer (score 3):

you can get the expansion panel icon on left by removing it from expandIcon and add it as a children in Summary something like this

```
<ExpansionPanel defaultExpanded={true}>
    <ExpansionPanelSummary aria-controls="panel1a-content">
     {this.state.expanded ? <RemoveIcon/> : <ExpandIcon />}
     <Typography component='h4' variant='h4'>My Expansion Panel</Typography>
    </ExpansionPanelSummary>
    <ExpansionPanelsDetails />
</ExpansionPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

The challenge is that the order is hardcoded into the codebase and you will not be able to use the `ExpansionPanel` as is.

If you look at the [implementation](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/ExpansionPanelSummary/ExpansionPanelSummary.js#L127-L142), you will find the code as below

```
      <div className={clsx(classes.content, { [classes.expanded]: expanded })}>{children}</div>
      {expandIcon && (
        <IconButton
          disabled={disabled}
          className={clsx(classes.expandIcon, {
            [classes.expanded]: expanded,
          })}
          edge="end"
          component="div"
          tabIndex={-1}
          aria-hidden
          {...IconButtonProps}
        >
          {expandIcon}
        </IconButton>
      )}
```

As you see the `<div>` contains the text and then the `IconButton` is displayed.

So, you may have to work with what's provided out of the box or create your own Component based on what material-UI provides.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

By setting **flexDirection: 'row-reverse'** in **ExpansionPanelSummay** we can achieve the same in the following way.

```
<Accordion>
    <ExpansionPanel>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary sx={{flexDirection: 'row-reverse'}}> // add here
            <Typography style={{marginLeft: '2rem'}}>Settlements</Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails>
            <Typography>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.</Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
    </ExpansionPanel>
</Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the CSS class like this:

notice the absolute position, in this way you can move the div that contains the icon whatever position you want with 'left' or 'right' properties

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  ExpansionPanelSummaryExpandedIcon: {
    '& div.MuiExpansionPanelSummary-expandIcon': {
      position: 'absolute',
      right: '5%',
    },
  }
}));
```

and then use in the ExpansionPanelSummary

```
<ExpansionPanelSummary
     expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
     aria-controls="panel1-content"
     id="panel1bh-header"
     className={classes.ExpansionPanelSummaryExpandedIcon}
>
```

references:
https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.3.0
https://v4-8-3.material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes